# A different type binomial expansion problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, binomial-theorem

Suppose we have $$(1+x+x^2)^n = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_{2n} x^{2n}.$$

What will be the value of $a_0^2 - a_1^2 + a_2^2 - \cdots + a_{2n}^2$?

The answer is $a_n$, but I can't solve it.

See, what I've done is substitute $x$ as $-\frac{1}{x}$ and I've got:

${\frac{(x^2-x+1)}{x^2}}^n = a_0 - \frac{a_1}{x} + \frac{a_2}{x^2}+...$

I've got the alternating signs but I can't get the squares of the numbers.

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many close votes. Yes this is basically a PSQ, but it's not exactly an easy question either, so it is quite possible that the OP has made zero progress even after a lot of thought.

Comment: @Mario I don't like double-standards on this site. If the OP has made zero progress after giving it a lot of thought, s/he should at least *say that* and share some of the thought s/he has given it. (Re: double standard...Level of difficulty is subjective. Believe it or not, there are folks who encounter "easy" questions that they too have given a lot of thought to, but are cut no slack.)

Comment: No, I've tried a little sir. I'll put up my work

Comment: @amWhy I'm not advocating any double standards, and I realize that difficulty is subjective. What I mean is that I consider it too harsh to require some progress to have been made on the problem. I personally don't like showing incorrect or incomplete work; my paper stays empty until I see the path to the end. (I am actually making an exception in my own answer below, in hopes that my current progress will enlighten someone else enough to finish the job.) As a result, it seems entirely reasonable to have zero to show for hours of thought on a hard (to the OP) problem.

Comment: Also, the OP does in fact say "I can't solve it", which under conventional usage means that he has attempted a solution and failed. Saying "I thought about it for a while and I still can't see how to get past step 0" is just more words for the same thing.

Comment: Hey, i did show some work,even though it could be wrong

Comment: @user34304 I know, I am referring to the original version of the problem which prompted the 4 close votes and responding to amWhy's objections.

Comment: As for using $-x$ in place of $x$, this is in fact a good way to alternate signs on the coefficients. But I don't know any polynomial manipulation to get a sum of squared coefficients. One observation to make, by replacing $x\mapsto\frac1x$ and multiplying by $x^{2n}$ on each side, is that $a_k=a_{2n-k}$, so the sequence is symmetric about $a_n$. Not sure how helpful this is though.

Comment: @Mario: Please know that I did not vote to close, nor did I downvote. I just don't like double standards. I'm **not** one of the militant "NO PSQs!" users of this site.

Comment: What is a PSQ, sir?

Comment: @user34304 Problem statement question - a question which looks like it was copied from a homework sheet.

Comment: The idea presented by the OP is a good one. It is pretty close to what both of the answers use. I see no reason to close this as a PSQ. The only idea missing is that of Cauchy products.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_ka_kx^k$. Then:

\begin{align}
(1+x^2+x^4)^n&=(1-x^{-1}+x^{-2})^n(1+x+x^2)^nx^{2n}\\
\sum_ja_jx^{2j}&=\sum_k(-1)^ka_kx^{-k}\sum_ja_jx^jx^{2n}\\
&=\sum_j\sum_k(-1)^ka_ka_jx^{2n+j-k}\\
&=\sum_j\sum_k(-1)^ka_ka_{k+j-2n}x^j\\
\end{align}

The $x^{2n}$ coefficient on the left side is $a_n$; the same coefficient on the right side is $\sum_k(-1)^ka_k^2$.

Comment: Sir, I am in 11th grade and this problem came in my test. I am not at all familiar with the math you've used in this answer. So please, can u try using an alternative method of my standard. Thank you

Comment: @user34304 Don't take this the wrong way, but my first priority is always to solve the problem. Once a solution is found, one can consider reductions to "elementary" methods, but my answer is still incomplete; I don't see *any* solutions, regardless of complexity, just yet.

Comment: Sorry, I understand

Comment: @user34304 The solution is now complete, and it only uses basic manipulations similar to those for proving binomial identities.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: A bit complex, but it seems to get the job done (+1). I didn't read your answer at first because when I first looked at the question, your answer was incomplete (and it looked very involved). Now that I have written my answer, I  see that yours is complete and that we both use some similar methods: Cauchy products and $(1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)=1+x^2+x^4$. I guess mine is a bit simpler because I noted that the coefficients are palindromic (which removes the need to extend the coefficients to other orders).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Color me confused. I see that you *do* mention the symmetry of the coefficients. Perhaps the remaining complexity (delving into the double indices) is simply left over from the earlier incarnation of your answer.

Comment: @robjohn Actually, we are using different methods. I am doing an induction proof, which shows that the difference $a_{n+1,n+1}-a_{n,n}=2a_{n,n+1}$ is equal to the sum $2\sum_k(-1)^ka_{n,k}a_{n,k-2}$ via the cauchy product method. I guess I should have realized that this same method can be applied to $\sum_k(-1)^ka_{n,k}^2$, but I guess the first proof is not necessarily the most elegant.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I noted that induction must have be intended, when I saw $$ \begin{align} &\sum_k(-1)^k(\color{#C00000}{a_{n,k}^2}+2a_{n,k}a_{n,k-2})\\ =&\color{#C00000}{a_{n,n}}+2\sum_k(-1)^ka_{n,k}a_{n,k-2}\\ \end{align} $$ and the only way to reconcile the equality of the red parts was to assume an inductive hypothesis. I don't see any other mention of induction, however. Things might be clearer if you made the induction explicit.

Comment: @robjohn Actually, I explain that step in the paragraph directly *afterward*, along with justifications for the other steps.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: ah, there it is. I thought I remembered seeing it, but I was somehow blinded in my last reading. Sorry about that.

Comment: @robjohn I want to completely rewrite this answer to eliminate the unnecessary induction and streamline the proof, but I'm not sure whether I should edit it or post a new answer.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: the current answer is a bit convoluted; personally, I would rewrite it (anyone with enough reputation can read the old version). If you really want to keep the current version, I would add a new answer because a single answer with both versions would probably be quite long and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kx^k\tag{1}
$$
we can look at the following in two ways
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}\right)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_k\frac1{x^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kx^{-k}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
or as
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1{x^2}+\frac1x+1\right)^n
&=\left(\frac{1+x+x^2}{x^2}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kx^{k-2n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_{2n-k}x^{-k}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(2)$ and $(3)$ show that $a_k$ is palindromic; that is,
$$
a_k=a_{2n-k}\tag{4}
$$
Furthermore, using $(1)$ and substituting $x\mapsto-x$, we get
$$
(1-x+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^ka_kx^k\tag{5}
$$
Using $(1)$, $(4)$, $(5)$, and the formula to multiply power series, we get the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n(1-x+x^2)^n$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^ka_ka_{2n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^ka_k^2\tag{6}
$$
We can use $(1)$ to get that  the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4)^n$ is
$$
a_n\tag{7}
$$
Noting that $(1+x+x^2)^n(1-x+x^2)^n=(1+x^2+x^4)^n$, $(6)$ and $(7)$ show that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^ka_k^2=a_n\tag{8}
$$